# Equivalent linear congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[image]

I totally don't know how to solve this question.
Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_of_Linear_Congruence and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruence_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Let $ax-b=mk$ then $\frac{a}{d}x-\frac{b}{d}=\frac{m}{d}k$ and vice versa.
Detailed:
$\Rightarrow$: If $x$ satisfied $ax\equiv b\pmod m$ means $ax-b=mk$, Since $d\mid b$ then we have $\frac{a}{d}x-\frac{b}{d}=\frac{m}{d}k$ and this means $\frac{a}{d}x\equiv \frac{b}{d}\pmod{\frac{m}{d}}$. So $x$ satisfied other equation.
$\Leftarrow$:  If $x$ satisfied $\frac{a}{d}x\equiv \frac{b}{d}\pmod{\frac{m}{d}}$ means $\frac{a}{d}x-\frac{b}{d}=\frac{m}{d}k$ then we have $ax-b=mk$ and this means $ax\equiv b\pmod m$. So $x$ satisfied other equation.
SO we prove twice sides of proposition.

Comment: Does this proof go through a if and only if situation? However the question is asking for two equivalent solution sets. How should I do?